# JavaScript converting object with same id to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting this result from my API :

[image]

But any with the same id (like the last 2) i would like to be grouped in an object so there would be only 3 items in the array (0,1,2) and the last one would be nested within the last one because it has a duplicate ID. It is ordered in the correct format from the SQL so i would like it to keep it's order.

There could be up to 50 with the same id that might need to nest, i tried using an array and the key but cant get the desired result

```
if(data.length > 0){
    console.log(value);
     try{
         if(value.id == s[key - 1].id){
           console.log("match");
           s.push(value);
         } else {
            orderobj.push(s);
         }

      } catch(ex){}
        console.log(orderobj);
  }
```

Comment: Grouped how? You have an array of objects - how would you combine objects with the same ID?

Comment: That is the question, i want [[obj1],[obj2],[[[obj3],[obj4]]]]

Comment: this doesn't make any sense.  What is the *actual keys* of your table?  it's hard to imagine that `id` is the primary key, if you are allowing duplicates;  why can't you just group these the way they are grouped in the database?

Comment: it isn't a primary key.. i'm sending that purposely so i know which items i need to group together. It's to do with multiple locations for products in a warehouse

Comment: Will items with the same id ALWAYS be sequential in the data? i.e: 1,2,3,3,3,4? or can you get 1,2,3,3,4,3?

Comment: How is this an AngularJS specific problem?

Comment: @Ben yes they will always be sequential

Comment: @Chris I didn't say it was but if there was any angular functions that would help i didn't think it would be a problem to include that it is Angular. Is it????

Comment: depending on your database schema, you may be able to do what you want with a `GROUP BY` clause in SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all of your like-ID's are sequential you can do a pretty simple check when creating a new collection from your API data. Just keep adding objects into an array until the ID's no longer match, then add that array into a parent array.

```js
var apiData = [
 {id: 1, text: '1asdf'},
  {id: 2, text: '2asdf'},
  {id: 3, text: '3asdf'},
  {id: 4, text: '4asdf'},
  {id: 4, text: '5asdf'},
];

var dataArray = [];

for(let i=0;i<apiData.length;++i) {
 var dataItem = [];
  
 dataItem.push(apiData[i]);
  
    while(i < apiData.length-1 && apiData[i].id === apiData[i+1].id) {
      ++i
      dataItem.push(apiData[i]);
    }

  dataArray.push(dataItem);
}

console.log('Final Array:', dataArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just make an object map with the ID as the key, and then an array of matching objects as the value. Then loop the object keys in order and create an array from all of that:

```
let objectMap = data.reduce(function(o, i) {
    if (!o[i.id]) o[i.id] = [];
    o[i.id].push(i)

    return o;
}, {})
```

And concat:

```
let sortedKeys = Object.keys(objectMap).sort();
let groupedData = sortedKeys.reduce(function(d, k) {
    d.push(objectMap[k]);
    return d;
}, []); //return format: [[{id:1}],[{id:2}],[{id:3},{id:3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    var apiData = [
   {id: 1, text: '1asdf'},
      {id: 2, text: '2asdf'},
      {id: 3, text: '3asdf'},
      {id: 4, text: '4asdf'},
      {id: 4, text: '5asdf'},
    ];

    var result = [];
    apiData.forEach((item) => {
   var saved = result.find((innerArr) => {
  return innerArr.find((innerItem) => innerItem.id === item.id) ? true : false;
   })

   if(saved){
  saved.push(item);
      } else {
  result.push([item]);
   }
 
    })
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce`. You can add objects in an array sharing the same `id` and then use `Object.values()` to get all the objects.

```js
var arr = [{id:'27', uid: '7', code: 'HV0010SML', productid: '1', datetime: '2017-10-06 15:57:17'},{id:'28', uid: '7', code: 'HV0010MED', productid: '1', datetime: '2017-10-06 15:57:17'},{id:'29', uid: '7', code: 'HV0010LGE', productid: '1', datetime: '2017-10-06 15:57:17'},{id:'29', uid: '7', code: 'HV0010LGE', productid: '1', datetime: '2017-10-06 15:57:17'}];

var combined = arr.reduce((hash, obj) => {
   return obj.id in hash ? hash[obj.id].push(obj) : hash[obj.id] = [obj], hash;
}, Object.create(null));

var result = Object.values(combined);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height: 100% !important}
```